Page jumps to top when inline editing question and answers simultaneously
As someone who likes to inline edit both question and all answers at the same time to reduce multiple bumping, I noticed since recently that the page jumps to the top when the question is currently on edit, and then clicking the edit link on an answer.
Steps to reproduce:

User already has edit posts privilege.
Find a Q&A with both question and answers editable, e.g. What are Stack Overflow unicoins? (many short answers).
Click 'Edit' on the question, leave the inline editor opens for the question.
Scroll to an answer with short body, thus the edit link is visible while the top of the answer is also visible on the screen (important).
Click 'Edit' on the answer.

After clicking 'Edit' on the answer, the page will jump to the top.
This does not occur if the top of the answer is not visible (because the answer is very long). In this case, clicking the 'edit' link will jump to the top of the answer as expected.
In case it is relevant: Windows 10/11, Chrome 126, zoom 100%, no browser extensions, display scale 100%/200%.

Able to reproduce in Mozilla Firefox 127.0.2 (64-bit), Windows 11 Pro.

No repro on iPadOS, Chrome. No scroll page at all on edit answer.
